# Java or JavaC Keeps Saying Package Not Found or Doesn't Exist

Tags: java, maven, import, jar, javac

I'm hitting a snag when attempting to run a Java File inside a Maven Project. I have it set up where I run a Java Class that does a bit of a setup before using run an exec to run the rest of the Tests in Maven. I can run program fine inside an IDE tool (Eclipse), but when I run Program from CMD or Git Bash, I keep getting errors stating that a ClassDef not found or package/import does not exist, (even though it works fine in IDE and on Mvn commands to test classes. I've attempted to use Javac - cp .  to see if the new setup would get rid of the errors, but I get similar errors. I've looked around for several different answers, they either don't fix the problem or put my project in a far worse state. Now, I'm not sure what is the exact cause of problem and determining the best solution to fix this.

Here's an example of my problem, I attempt to compile one of the java files that is connected to Java file I want to run, that will run Maven:

```
 $ javac -d build/classes -sourcepath src -cp target/classes src/AppiumDriverSetUp_Lib/XMLMaker.java
src\AppiumDriverSetUp_Lib\XMLMaker.java:28: error: package io.appium.java_client does not exist
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
                            ^
src\AppiumDriverSetUp_Lib\XMLMaker.java:29: error: package io.appium.java_client does not exist
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
                            ^
src\AppiumDriverSetUp_Lib\XMLMaker.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
        public void setupDriverXMLFile(List <AppiumDriver<MobileElement>> driverList) {
                                             ^
  symbol:   class AppiumDriver
  location: class XMLMaker
src\AppiumDriverSetUp_Lib\XMLMaker.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
        public void setupDriverXMLFile(List <AppiumDriver<MobileElement>> driverList) {
                                                          ^
  symbol:   class MobileElement
  location: class XMLMaker
src\AppiumDriverSetUp_Lib\XMLMaker.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
                        for(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver: driverList) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class AppiumDriver
  location: class XMLMaker
src\AppiumDriverSetUp_Lib\XMLMaker.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
                        for(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver: driverList) {
                                         ^
  symbol:   class MobileElement
  location: class XMLMaker
6 errors
```

XMLMaker File in AppiumDriverSetUp_Lib Package:

```
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;

public class XMLMaker {



    public DocumentBuilderFactory docDriverSetup;

    public DocumentBuilder driverSetup;

    public int connectedDevices = 0;

    public Document doc;


    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

    Transformer transformer;


    public void setupDriverXMLFile(List <AppiumDriver<MobileElement>> driverList) {

        System.out.println("List size: "+ driverList.size());
        try {

            docDriverSetup = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

            driverSetup = docDriverSetup.newDocumentBuilder();

            doc = driverSetup.newDocument();

            transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd");

            Element suiteElement = doc.createElement("suite");
            suiteElement.setAttribute("name", "All-tests");

            for(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver: driverList) {

                Element rootElement = doc.createElement("test");
                suiteElement.appendChild(rootElement);
                rootElement.setAttribute("name", (String) driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("deviceId"));

                Element deviceNameEle = doc.createElement("parameter");
                deviceNameEle.setAttribute("name", "deviceName");
                deviceNameEle.setAttribute("value", (String) driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("deviceId"));
                rootElement.appendChild(deviceNameEle);

                Element platformEle = doc.createElement("parameter");
                platformEle.setAttribute("name", "platform");
                platformEle.setAttribute("value", driver.getPlatformName()+"");
                rootElement.appendChild(platformEle);

                Element udidEle = doc.createElement("parameter");
                udidEle.setAttribute("name", "udid");
                udidEle.setAttribute("value", (String)driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("udid"));
                rootElement.appendChild(udidEle);

                Element urlPort = doc.createElement("parameter");
                urlPort.setAttribute("name", "URL");
                urlPort.setAttribute("value", (String)driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("appiumURL"));
                rootElement.appendChild(urlPort);

                Element devicePort = doc.createElement("parameter");

                if((driver.getPlatformName()+"").
                        toLowerCase().contains("android")) {
                        devicePort.setAttribute("name", "port");
                        devicePort.setAttribute("value", driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("systemPort")+"");

                }
                if ((driver.getPlatformName()+"").
                        toLowerCase().contains("ios")) {
                        devicePort.setAttribute("name", "port");
                        devicePort.setAttribute("value", (String)driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("wdaLocalPort"));
                }

                rootElement.appendChild(devicePort);

                Element packages = doc.createElement("packages");
                rootElement.appendChild(packages);
                Element packageName = doc.createElement("package");
                packageName.setAttribute("name", "BaseTest");
                packages.appendChild(packageName);


                connectedDevices++;
            }   
            suiteElement.setAttribute("parallel", "tests");
            suiteElement.setAttribute("thread-count", connectedDevices+"");
            doc.appendChild(suiteElement);

        } catch(ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }


    public void createDriverFile() throws TransformerConfigurationException, InterruptedException, IOException {

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

        FileOutputStream streamNewFile = new FileOutputStream("./drivers.xml");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(streamNewFile);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(pw);


        try {

            transformer.transform(source, result);
            result.getWriter().close();

            System.out.println("File Updated");



        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error updating the file");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Unable to close output stream");
        }

    }

}
```

And here is the problem when I try to compile the Java File to start the test:

```
$ javac -d build/classes -sourcepath src -cp target/classes src/BaseTest/DriverTest.java
src\BaseTest\DriverTest.java:29: error: cannot access AppiumDriver
                makeFile.setupDriverXMLFile(createDrivers.getActiveList());
                        ^
  class file for io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver not found
1 error
```

DriverTest in BaseTest package:

```
import AppiumDriverSetUp_Lib.AppiumDriverSetup;
import AppiumDriverSetUp_Lib.XMLMaker;

public class DriverTest {

    public AppiumDriverSetup createDrivers = new AppiumDriverSetup();

    public XMLMaker makeFile = new XMLMaker();

    public static void main(String [] args) throws TransformerConfigurationException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Setting up drivers:");

        DriverTest startTest = new DriverTest();
        startTest.driverFileSetup();
        startTest.runSuite();
    }

    public void driverFileSetup() throws IOException, TransformerConfigurationException, InterruptedException {
        createDrivers.makeList();
        makeFile.setupDriverXMLFile(createDrivers.getActiveList());
        makeFile.createDriverFile();
    }

    public void runSuite() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String cmd = "cmd /c mvn test -Dplat="+System.getProperty("plat");
        Process p = rt.exec(cmd);
        InputStream input = p.getInputStream();
        testFeed(input, System.out);
        p.waitFor();
    }

    public void testFeed(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        while (true) {
            int c = in.read();
            if (c == -1) {
                break;
            }
            out.write((char)c);
        }
    }

}
```

In my XMLMaker class, it already has the correct imports for AppiumDriver and MobileElement, as one of the correct import options in my IDE. And no issue if I run it with mvn. I think the problem is tied to the dependencies I have for this project. Has anyone experienced a case like this?

Comment: Can you please edit your question with XMLMaker.java file?or you can also check package name which you have specified in this class might be the reason for this issue.

Comment: @GauravRai1512 Sure, I edit the question to include Java Files for XMLMaker, which is in package: AppiumDriverSetUp_Lib and Driver Test, Whixh is in the package: BaseTest. I'll add the imports which bash/cmd state class not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like whatever you are doing in the command line doesn't quite include the classes you need to build it. In Eclipse you probably have a reference to the necessary JAR files.

My advice - if you are using Maven to achieve build automation (which you should) it should be used in its entirety where the build process will do all of this for you automatically.

In your case I guess just make sure javac knows where to find the jar files for XMLMaker and the necessary dependencies can be found.

Comment: That would be easier to let Maven to do all the work, but the problem is I want drivers.xml called in XMLMaker to be dynamic based on what mobile devices are connected. When I attempted to set it up to run before running the test suite (@BeforeSuite) any changes make in drivers xml in order to run tests in that same runtime, didn't get updated after the session was over. It was after doing some research, that Maven makes a sort of static reference of original values drivers.xml had making any changes. This approach, it allows drivers.xml to update when I close PrintWriter at the end.

Comment: Found a solution run my Java file DriverTest using Maven. I can run: mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="BaseTest.DriverTest" <any system properties or arguments I want to include> and it runs the DriverTest, which then runs the Runtime exec: mvn test after setup.